# Conditional join Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, conditional-statements

I have a table that includes some information about each time a user uses mobile or web app ie

| id | platform |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | web |
| 1 | mobile |
| 2 | web |
| 2 | web |

I want to join another table with this table which says what each user uses as a phone_model

| id | phone_model |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | iphone |
| 2 | android |

But I want to conditionally join these so that only the mobile entries show the phone_model and the web row to be kept empty, ie only join that information in cases where platform = 'mobile'

| id | platform | phone_model |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | web |  |
| 1 | mobile | Iphone |
| 2 | web |  |
| 2 | web |  |

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want a `left join`:

```
select t1.*, t2.phone_model
from table1 t1 left join
     table2 t2
     on t2.id = t1.id and t1.platform = 'mobile';
```